# Gentoo: после перезагрузки "cannot open root device sda3 or unknown-block(0,0): error -6"

Tags: linux, kernel, boot, gentoo

Ставлю Gentoo, скомпилировал ядро через genkernel, установил grub, перезагрузился. Получаю ошибки:

> Gentoo: cannot open root device sda3 or unknown-block(0,0): error -6
>   Please append a correct "root=" boot option; here are the available partitions:Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)CPU: 0 PID: 1 comm swapper/0 Not tained 3.10.17-gentoo ...

fdisk /dev/sda:

```
/dev/sda1 2048 67583 32768 83 Linux
/dev/sda2 67584 1116159 524288 83 Linux
/dev/sda3 1116160 16777215 7830528 83 Linux
```

/etc/fstab:

```
/dev/sda1 /boot ext2 defaults,noatime 1 2
/dev/sda3 / ext3 noatime 0 1/dev/sda2 none swap sw 0 0
```

Comment: и что самое прикольное, оба нижних ответа правильные :) Вот такая она, Гента :)

Answer (score 1):

grub тут абсолютно не при делах. Не хватает либо драйвера контроллера или ФС, либо ядру неверно передан параметр root, о чем оно и глаголет =) Разметку диска бы увидеть.

Comment: fdist /dev/sda/dev/sda1  2048  67583  32768 83 Linux/dev/sda2  67584 1116159 524288 83 Linux/dev/sda3  1116160 16777215 7830528 83 Linuxhttp://clip2net.com/s/6a5zZJ#/etc/fstab/dev/sda1 /boot ext2 defaults,noatime 1 2/dev/sda3 / ext3 noatime 0 1/dev/sda2 none swap sw 0 0http://clip2net.com/s/6a5zrpА вот здесь конфиг grub:http://clip2net.com/s/6a5L6xустановка grub:http://clip2net.com/s/6a5NU0

Comment: а сейчас другая ошибка появляетсяhttp://clip2net.com/s/6a5RkM

Comment: Измените параметр real_root на /dev/sda3. В root должен передаваться раздел с корневой ФС, а не раздел с загрузчиком =)P.S. А лучше вообще убрать real_root и оставить только root=/dev/sda3.

Answer (score 0):

GRUB куда ставил - на девайс или на раздел в девайсе? И есть ли там ещё системы, кроме? В общем, проблема в том, что GRUB путается с разделами, и не может найти загрузчика системы. Тем более, что это sda3! Можно всё поправить и с любого лайв-диска, но это вот, я думаю, поможет вам точно: http://www.supergrubdisk.org/